# Scrolling an accordion with touch event listeners

Tags: javascript, touch, dom-events

I'm creating a list of links that a user can tap and reveal children items, much like an accordion. Here is an example of what I'm aiming for (from the Metro iPhone app). Mine is obviously built with HTML, JS and CSS.

[image]

Ideally I don't want to use a `click` event because of [the delay before it fires on mobile devices](https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons) but by listening for `touchstart` I have the issue that if the user moves their finger over the list to scroll it up or down then it instantly fires an open or close event on the accordion. This does not happen with `click`. I'm having similar issues with `touchend` as well.

What I would ideally prefer is the behaviour that the app exhibits, which is being able to scroll the list with a finger and when an item is touched it instantly opens or closes.

If you'd like to see the issue, I have a crude version setup here - [http://goo . gl/2Z1fc](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1709558/ipad-nav/nav.html)

Comment: Have you considered using CSS declaration {-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;overflow:scroll;} for the accordion?

Comment: Reading about it here - http://johanbrook.com/browsers/native-momentum-scrolling-ios-5/ It seems to bear no relevance to my question. That concerns scrolling momentum, which I have no issue with.